# JQuery - Concatenate multiple/variable table values into a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'll apologise now for the newbie question!

I have a HTML table with 3 columns and 5 rows.   I have input fields, with unique ID's, in columns across 4 rows so I can capture data entered by the user.   However, I need to take all values entered and concatenate them into one string in a hidden field so it can be submitted to the database.

The string needs to have a delimiter (tbc) and only have the "latest" value that has been entered into a column.  I say this because I had something working that fired with a Change event but this was just concatenating every value entered with a delimiter - e.g. when I entered 'Hello' into a column then this was written to the string and I replaced this with 'Bye' then this was written to the string as 'Hello, Bye' when I just wanted the last value entered ('Bye').  I know this is expected behaviour with the Change event.

Ideally, I would like this script to fire every time a value is entered into the table as it is extremely difficult to do so when a button is clicked due to the nature of the software I am using.

Can anyone please offer any guidance on this?

Here's my Table and hidden field:

```html
<table class="table table-striped" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" id="BookChap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Chapter Number</th>
      <th>Chapter Title</th>
      <th>Completed?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="1a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="1b" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="2a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="2b" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="3a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="3b" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="4a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="4b" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>



<input id="result" type="hidden" value="">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE - you have not shown any effort. You need to loop over each field `.on("input"...` of each field. However why not do the concatenation on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each field .on("input"... of each field.

However why not do the concatenation on the server?

Anyway, here is an example - note I changed one class from sv-form-control

```js
$(function() {
  $(".form-control").on("input",function() {
    var arr = [];
    $(".form-control").each(function() {
      if (this.value) arr.push(this.value);
    });
    if (arr.length>0) $("#result").val(arr.join("|")); // or TBC instead of |
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="result" type="text" value="" />
<table class="table table-striped" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" id="BookChap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Chapter Number</th>
      <th>Chapter Title</th>
      <th>Completed?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="1a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="1b" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="2a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="2b" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="3a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="3b" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4.</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" id="4a"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="4b" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of change event, you can use click event on button. On button click loop all the table rows and construct string based on your need.

Comment: This is a comment. Write an answer instead including code. Then you will get enough rep to be allowed to comment. Do note OP just said he cannot use a button